# 1950s Sci-Fi film with beautiful woman alien in flying saucer in a snowy landscape

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, flying-saucer

What is the name of the 1950s sci-fi film that takes place in a "snow-covered landscape" (like the Arctic), as another posted question put it.

At the end of the film a man - one of the main characters, I imagine - is almost hypnotically attracted to walk to a flying saucer in the snow, lured by a beautiful woman (human-looking alien.)  If I remember correctly, there was very strange music playing during this scene, maybe even a Theremin (an early electronic instrument.) I'm pretty sure I saw it on TV sometime between 1956-58.

I was absolutely fascinated by it, especially that last scene (although I was only 5 to 7 years old at the time I saw it.) I've been trying to find out the name of this film for years and still no luck.  I would appreciate knowing what it is.

Comment: How that woman was dressed, i.e. something common or, may be, bright and shiny or so?

Answer (score 3):

It may be the film '[The Flying Saucer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flying_Saucer)' directed by Mikel Conrad. It is set in a Alaska during winter which involves the 'snow-covered landscape' element.

> American Intelligence officials learn that Soviet spies have begun exploring a remote region of the Alaskan Territory in search of answers to the worldwide reports of "flying saucers". A wealthy American playboy, Mike Trent (Mikel Conrad), who was raised in that remote region, is recruited by intelligence officer Hank Thorn (Russell Hicks) to assist a Secret Service agent in exploring that area to discover what the Soviets may have found.

> To his pleasant surprise, Mike discovers the agent is an attractive woman named Vee Langley (Pat Garrison). They set off together and slowly become mutually attracted to each other. Their cover story is that Mike is suffering from a nervous breakdown and she is his private nurse. At Mike's family's wilderness lodge, they are met by a foreign-accented caretaker named Hans (Hantz von Teuffen), new to the job.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to elaborate on the ways in which this matches the film described in the question. For example, does it include the specific scene described in the question?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion about The Flying Saucer.  It was a good guess but I scanned through it and it isn't the one I have in mind, even though the last 5 or 6 minutes are in a snowy landscape.  Also, as the another comment about how the woman alien was dressed, I'm not sure but I think she was wearing something sexy and skimpy that wouldn't be worn by any earthling in a snowy landscape.

Answer (score 0):

It could be Devil girl from Mars (1954)
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0046907/

The titular girl from Mars is played by the beautiful Patricia Laffan wearing a black PVC outfit with a mini skirt and a cape.

Comment: The movie doesn't look like it's shot in a snowy landscape...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about The Devil Girl from Mars.  It is a good guess but I scanned the movie and though interesting, it isn't the one I had in mind.